# Centring a grid column

Tags: css

How can I center a grid column? This is my current code

```
.example-grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

However, all the grid items are aligned to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
section {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 4px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

div{
  background:#777;
  color:#fff;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</section>
```

Instead of `align-items: center;`, you have to use `align-content: center;`.

Everything else looks fine :)

`align-items` property is a Flexbox property not a CSS-Grid property

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: Can you show you code dear @larkx 

I think you need to center the individual items in that case. 

Go to codepen.io here. First check what I have done and then do let me know, How can I help you better. :)

https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/MWveVog

Comment: Ah, I've resolved it now that you provided the full code. I just need to edit some of the other styles. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, I don't suppose you could help me promptly with something else. I have this code here to horizontally center my div, however - it's not vertically centring. How can I change it to do both? (Resulting in the div being in the middle of my screen)
```
.div-center {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Hey My Friend :) @larkx I would suggest you watch this free CSS-Grid 1 hour course. 
https://scrimba.com/learn/cssgrid

This would help you understand things better :)

Answer (score 0):

Your *display* property must be **inline-grid** instead of **grid**.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :/